# Product Star Ratings Summary not displaying in every store view

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, review, scope

On a product page of our site when customers leave reviews with star ratings, the start rating summary (average) is displayed at the top of the product page.

[image]

But I've noticed that when we change the store view the star rating summary  disappears from the top of the page and only the rating links remain.

[image]

I've looked at the code in: *app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/helper/summary.phtml*

```
<?php if ($this->getRatingSummary()):?>
    <div class="rating-box">
        <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary() ?>%"></div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

And `$this->getRatingSummary()` returns '0' rather than '100' when I change the store view from the store view in which the customer left their review in.

Is there anyway I can display the star ratings summary no matter what the store view is?

On the admin panel I've set the review to be visible in all store views i.e. **Catalog > Reviews and Ratings > Customer Reviews > All Reviews**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new *review/helper/summary.phtml* template file in our custom theme and updated the code to:

```
<?php
$reviewSummary = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary');
$storeStructure = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoresStructure();
$productId = $this->getProduct()->getId();
$avgRating = 0;
$cumulativeRating = 0;
$storesWithRatings = 0;
foreach($storeStructure as $websiteStructure){
    foreach($websiteStructure[children] as $storeInfo){
        $storeID = $storeInfo[value];
        array_push($storeIds,$storeID);
        $currentRating = $reviewSummary->setStoreId($storeID)->load($productId)->getRatingSummary();
        if ($currentRating) {
            $storesWithRatings++;
        }
        $cumulativeRating = $cumulativeRating + $currentRating;
    }
}

if ($cumulativeRating && $storesWithRatings) {
    $avgRating = $cumulativeRating / $storesWithRatings;
}
?>
<div class="ratings">
    <?php if ($avgRating):?>
        <div class="rating-box">
            <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $avgRating ?>%"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endif;?>
```

This code is iterating over an array of each of the stores, getting the rating score for each of the products and putting the average rating from each of the stores into a variable called `$avgRating`.

A drawback to this approach is that even if a review is not visible in the current store view, it's rating will be added to the `avgRating`.

I think that in Magento when you set a review to be visible in a store view, the same should be applied to the ratingSummary.

Similarly, to have the star ratings to appear on the review itself no matter what the store view I followed this approach:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/17731/6549

Comment: This seems to be overkill. You can remove store filter for the review query. `Mage_Review_Model_Review#getEntitySummary()`, comment the line where it said `->setStoreId($storeId)`. Of course, you should override, instead of modify core. But that should be it.